# `[]` in swift3.0 closure

Tags: swift, closures

I do not understand the following code:

```
    var i = 20
    var cb = {
        [i] in
        i
    }
    i = 30
    print(cb()) // 20
```

- What does this syntax express: `[i] in i`?
- I was expecting this prints `30`. Why does it print `20`?

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: Please comment down votes. I think this is a good question.

Comment: @shallowThought How can **you** know what the OP expects? I don't like when editors change personal / opinion based parts of the question.

Comment: I found the question clear and easy to understand and wanted to help others understanding it too (as you asked in your comment and there where downvote I did not understand).

Answer (score 2):

`[i]` is a *capture list* for the closure.

From [Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html) in "The Swift Programming Language" (emphasis added):

> **Closure Expression**
>
> A capture list is written as a comma separated list of expressions surrounded by square brackets, before the list of parameters. If you use a capture list, you must also use the in keyword, even if you omit the parameter names, parameter types, and return type.
>
> The entries in the capture list are **initialized when the closure is created.** For each entry in the capture list, a constant is initialized to the value of the constant or variable that has the same name in the surrounding scope.

In your example, when the closure is created, a constant `i`
with the value of the outer `i` *at that time*  (i.e. `20`) is created for the closure. When the closure is executed, the value of
that constant is returned.

Comment: Did not know this one. Thanks!